# JtextEditorPane - How to prevent copy and paste from wrapping text in html paragraph tags?

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane, dom

I have:

```
HTMLDocument document = new HTMLDocument();
JTextPane htmlEditorPane = new JTextPane(document)
htmlEditorPane.setContentType("text/html");
```

I then select some text in the middle of a sentence and call (wrapped in the appropriate ActionListeners):

```
htmlEditorPane.copy();
htmlEditorPane.paste();
```

For whatever reason whenever I do this the text that is copy and pasted is wrapped in `<p>` tags. How can I keep all the formatting but the `<p>` tags that seem to be added?

Comment: no answer, just @StanislavL answering a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17437440/203657) - in short: you need your own htmldocument that tries harder to behave as intuitively expected

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is too high level, and for someone like me who isn't very familiar with these concepts that's the difficult part. I just added a comment. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getDefaultRootElement()` and investigate children of the root. There should be head and body. Then go deeper and check children of children.

You can use this [tool](http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneStructureTool.html) to check document's and view's structure.